# images from media file wont get displayed in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new to django and I've been playing around with uploading pictures then displaying them. ... well *trying* to display them.

Whenever I try to display the image from a template, I just get the broken image link icon.

I'm using the sqlite3 server

settings.py

```py
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
def location(f):
    return os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, f)
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = location('media/')
```

models.py

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
```

views.py

```py
from imageupload.settings import MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL

def main(request):
    imgs = Image.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'images': imgs, 'media_root': MEDIA_ROOT, 'media_url': MEDIA_URL})
```

url.py

```py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Right now I've just used the admin to upload images. And that seems to work fine, they go to where I expect

But when I try to display them:
template

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <img src="<correct path to project>/media/images/photo_1.JPG" />

    {% for img in images %}
    <img src="{{ media_root }}{{ img.image.name }}" />
    <img src="{{ media_url }}{{ img.image.name }}" />
    <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" />
    {% endfor %}
</html>
```

I get the broken icon for each one.
The browser source code shows me:

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <img src="<correct path to project>/media/images/photo_1.JPG" />    
    <img src="<correct path to project>/media/images/photo_1.JPG" />    
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/photo_1.JPG" />
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/photo_1.JPG" />
</html>
```

that makes sense, I only have one photo uploaded.
and if I copy one of the hard links and put it into some other html file ...it works

Comment: You can use {% get_media_prefix %} to get MEDIA_URL.
Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Oh FFS....

aperently it's

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**NOT**

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
```

...despite `#'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'` being written right next to it

working img link looks like so:

```
<img src="/media/images/photo_1.JPG" />
```

you definitely need the:

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in the url file also

Comment: this is my first time seeing someone saying "FFS" on stackoverflow. I think it's contrary to the atmosphere of SO

Answer (score 14):

For me, I did the following two things:

Define media url in the **settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and then in the project's **urls.py**, defined serving url for development and production purpose:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('django_app.urls')),
]
# Serving the media files in development mode
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
else:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

then you can reference the image in the media folder in the template like this:

```
<img src="media/path_to_image" />
```

Note: Don't forget to set the **DEBUG** flag to **False** in the settings.py for production.

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking for display images in development environment try this:

settings.py

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'statics')
STATIC_URL = '/statics/'
```

urls.py

```
# somebody import this from settings
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  
urlpatterns += patterns('', 
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')})
)
```

html view file *.html:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/content_top_edit_form.png">
```

this means we have a **img** folder in static folder. in your case you can change this by

if you see your browser html must be seen like this:

```
<img src="/static/img/content_top_edit_form.png">
```

Comment: hey thanks for your response. I tried it and it still doesn't seem to work though

Answer (score 0):

in the template use {{img.image.name.url}}