# Django - How can I load images created by site using image uploaded by users?

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

For any image uploaded by the user, I am generating a Thumbnail. The user uploaded image and thumbnail are stored like this.

```
 media_cdn (folder)
  -user_name_1 (folder)
  -user_name_2 (folder)
  --post_1_title_slug (folder)
  ---300x180 (folder)
  ----300x180_user_uploaded_image_1.png
  ---user_uploaded_image_1.png
  --post_2_title_slug (folder)
  -user_name_3 (folder)
```

Since I am using ImageField in models, I can easily use `{{ appname.image.url }}` in templates, but this will load the image uploaded. I want to load the thumbnail.

I search on stackoverflow and most people are saying to use `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776969/images-from-media-file-wont-get-displayed-in-django-template)

I am leaning towards `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` because, in the future, the website will be generating more images based on the same user uploaded images.

I am using this as of now,

```
<img src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{user.username}}/{{ upload.slug }}/300x180/300x180_{{ upload.get_filename }}'>
```

this is giving out this in the page, (from Inspect element)

```
/user_name/file_slug/300x180/300x180_image_name.png
```

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}` is not giving its correct url.

FYI,

`get_filename` is from models.py where I wrote this to get the file name

```
    def get_filename(self):
        return(os.path.basename(self.image.name))
```

how can I make this work?
I am Using `Django 1.11.5`, and `Pillow 4.2.1`