# Not able to display image uploaded using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I was able to upload image using views and templates in django but was not able to display those images. I could only display images stored in static folder but not from the media folder or any other location. I have done all the steps mentioned in docs and in other solution but this is not working for me.

I created a model which looks like

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/')
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

and my forms.py is

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['image', 'description', 'quantity']
```

my views.py is like this

```
@login_required
def display_products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'farmer/display_products.html', {'products': products})

@login_required
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = ProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('display_products')
    return render(request, 'farmer/my_products.html', {'form': form})
```

my file is like this

```
{% load static %}
{% for product in products %}

    <div class="">
        <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
        {{product.image.url}}
        image: <img src='{{product.image.url}}' alt="sample">
        <p>description: {{ product.description }}
        quantity: {{ product.quantity }}
        </p>
    </div>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static/css',
]
LOGIN_URL = 'login'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
DEBUG = True
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', views_auth.sign_in, name='login'),
        path('logout/', views_auth.sign_out, name='logout'),
        path('register/', views_auth.sign_up, name='register'),
        path('display_products/', views_farmer.display_products, name='display_products'),
        path('upload/', views_farmer.upload, name='upload'),
    ]
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10776969/16770846) answer your question?

Comment: Indeed but not from the answer marked working but from 2nd reply. The solution was I had to make changes in projects urls.py I was making changes in urls.py of app.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to make the changes in urls.py of project not of the urls.py of app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("main/", include("main.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("farmer/", include("farmer.urls")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```